# I want to reset all the validation of the form on a click of one of the radio button

Tags: jquery

I have two radio buttons and I want to reset all the validation of the form on a click of one of the radio button, I have used jquery for the from validation.

my code is:-

```
<p class="radio_paragraph">

  <form:label for="beneficiaryType" path="beneficiaryType" 
              cssClass="form_label">    
     Are you 13 years or older?
  </form:label>

  <span id="beneficiaryError" style="display:none;color: red;"></span><br />

  <form:radiobutton path="beneficiaryType" 
                    value="YES" 
                    label="YES" 
                    cssClass="form_radio" />

  <form:radiobutton path="beneficiaryType" 
                    value="NO" 
                    label="NO"
                    cssClass="form_radio" />                    
</p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that resetForm is a method on the validator object returned by a.validate(...), and not on the jQuery object itself.

```
function resetValidator(){
var a = $("#yourFormName").validate();
a.resetForm();

}
```

Answer (score 2):

On radio click event you can call this

```
$('.form_radio').on('click', function() {  

     if( this.checked){
         var validator = $("#myform").validate();
         validator.resetForm();
     }
});
```